# Remove decimals in Pandas column names

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe with `numpy.float64` as the column names.

```
df =
     2006.0   2007.0   2008.0   2009.0
0       foo      foo      bar      bar
1       foo      foo      bar      bar
```

I'd like to change them to be strings and remove the decimal places:

```
df =
       2006     2007     2008     2009
0       foo      foo      bar      bar
1       foo      foo      bar      bar
```

I've tried saving the columns out to a list with `df.columns.tolist()` and changing them there but I've had no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert the type with `.astype`

```
In [312]: df.columns = df.columns.astype(int)

In [313]: df
Out[313]:
  2006 2007 2008 2009
0  foo  foo  bar  bar
1  foo  foo  bar  bar
```

Or use `.map` and convert to string type.

```
In [338]: df.columns.map('{:g}'.format)
Out[338]: Index(['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009'], dtype='object')

In [319]: df.columns.map(int)
Out[319]: Int64Index([2006, 2007, 2008, 2009], dtype='int64')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to `float` before converting to `int` and then `str`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.values.astype(float).astype(int).astype(str)

print(df.columns)

Index(['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009'], dtype='object')
```

Seems long-winded, but at least we are working with the underlying NumPy array.

Answer (score 0):

```
using numpy:
>>> df.columns = np.int64(df.columns).astype(str)
```